# What are the Siddhis associated with each of the Chakras based on the scriptures?

Tags: tantra, siddhi, chakras, kundalini

What are the Siddhis that are obtained by mastering each of the Chakras through kundalini according to our scriptures? Please mention your sources in the answers.

Comment: According to Uddav geeta spirtual enlightenement is the  first step in acquiring siddi all the other will flow with such ease no need separately try for this.. for enlightened person this magic show.. he is not all interested in doing magic.. expect in rare case where its necessary to prove the existing of higher god above.. and for the lords fame only its done if its done for other purpose it will distructive for individual may  to take back to lower realms hard to recover

Comment: Siddhis are obstacles on the way , not powers.

Answer (score 3):

According to [1-4], the most common siddhis obtainable through mastering kundalini are:

1. Aṇimā: the ability to become smaller than the smallest, reducing one's body to the size of an atom or even become invisible.
2. Mahimā: the ability to become infinitely large, expanding one's body to an infinitely large size.
3. Laghimā: the ability to become weightless or lighter than air.
4. Prāpti: the ability to instantaneously travel or be anywhere at will.
5. Prākāmya: the ability to achieve or realize whatever one desires.
6. Īśiṭva: the ability to control nature, individuals, organisms, etc. Supremacy over nature and ability to force influence upon anyone.
7. Vaśiṭva: the ability to control all material elements or natural forces.
8. Kāma-avasayitva (per Kṣemarāja and Vyasa): satisfaction, suppression of desire.

References:

[1] Subramuniyaswami, Sivaya (1997). Glossary - Siddhi. USA: Himalayan Academy. ISBN 978-0945497974. Search: Siddhi.

[2] Danielou, Alain (1987). While the Gods Play: Shaiva Oracles and Predictions on the Cycles of History and the Destiny of Mankind; Inner Traditions International.

[3] Jacobsen, Knut A., ed. (2011). Yoga Powers. Leiden: Brill. pp. 165, 204, 285. ISBN 978-9004212145.

[4] The Concise Srimad Bhagavatam, trans. Swami Venkatesananda, SUNY Press 1989, ISBN 0-7914-0149-9.

Answer (score -2):

If one can raise the kundalini power from mooladhara to the sahasrara chakra, the soul will reach its ultimate goal or enlightenment. It will attain a blissful state or samadhi state.

Ashtama siddhi can be attained after mastering the first chakra called mooladhara itself and once the kundalini started awakening. Ashtama siddhi is a primary achievement in a spiritual life. There are many things beyond that. I am not going to give you much reference about this. But, I can give you a solid proof. Shri Yantra is my illustration. Shri Yantra is considered as Yantra Raja in the world of Mantra, Thantra and Yantra practices of worshiping the God/Godesses. This yantra holds the above three within itself.

I thought of sharing a detailed information about Shri Yantra in my blog by this month.

Link to my personal blog: https://rkkrishnaa.in/

This yantra operates in such a way that how chakra functions in our human body. It has a nine avarna called navavarna, each set of avarna denotes a chakra. By worshipping that particular avarna makes you master in that chakra.

Finally, If you look at the first avarana in the Shri Yantra, The residing devate are Sapta kannimars, Ashtama siddhi, Mahalakshmi. The first avarana in Shri yantra denotes mooladhara chakra. Worshipping the first avarana helps to achieve first avarana related stuff.